# Azure TTS neural voice audio file is created abnormally in 1 byte size

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

Azure TTS standard voice audio files are generated normally.  However, for neural voice, the audio file is generated abnormally with the size of 1 byte.  The code is below.

C# code

```
public static async Task SynthesizeAudioAsync()
{
   var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxxxxxxxxKey", "xxxxxxxRegion");
   using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, null);

   var ssml = File.ReadAllText("C:/ssml.xml");
   var result = await synthesizer.SpeakSsmlAsync(ssml);

​   using var stream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result);
   await stream.SaveToWaveFileAsync("C:/file.wav");
}
```

ssml.xml - The file below, set to standard voice, works fine.

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
  <voice name="en-GB-George-Apollo">
    When you're on the motorway, it's a good idea to use a sat-nav.
  </voice>
</speak>
```

ssml.xml - However, the following file set for neural voice does not work, and an empty sound source file is created.

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
  <voice name="en-US-AriaNeural">
    When you're on the motorway, it's a good idea to use a sat-nav.
  </voice>
</speak>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the behavior you have described due to some issues, the Speech service has returned no audio bytes.

I have checked the SSML file at my end it works completely fine i.e. there is no issues with the SSML.

As a next step to the solution, I would recommend you to add error handling code to give better picture of the error and take the action accordingly :

```
    var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxxxxxxxxKey", "xxxxxxxRegion");
    using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, null);

    var ssml = File.ReadAllText("C:/ssml.xml");
    var result = await synthesizer.SpeakSsmlAsync(ssml);
    if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
    {
        var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");
        if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
        {
        Console.WriteLine ("No error ")
         using var stream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result);
            await stream.SaveToWaveFileAsync("C:/file.wav");

        }

        else if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
        {
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                
            }
        }
```

The above piece of modification will provide friendly error message on the console app.

**Note :** If you are not using the console app, you will have modify the code.

**Sample output :**

This is just a sample output. the error you might see would be different.
[image]

Comment: Solved thanks to good advice. I changed the resource region to eastus and it worked fine.

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work